# Images wont show up on my canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a simple game from a tutorial that I found on the internet. The link is right here in case you want to reference it. http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/. There are 3 images that need to be loaded onto the canvas. One is the background image. The second is the image of your player in the game (the hero). The third image is the monster image that you need to move your character to. I have a folder called 'main' that has an images folder in it that has all 3 images saved as png. There is a js folder with my js file called 'games.js'. There is also the html file called simple_canvas_game.html. Again, I am asking this question because I cannot get the images to load into my browser which is google chrome. Please help. My code is below.

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/background.png";

// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/hero.png";

// Monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function () {
    monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "images/monster.png";

// Game objects
var hero = {
    speed: 256 // movement in pixels per second
};
var monster = {};
var monstersCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

//New game 
var reset = function() {
    hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
    hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

    monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
}

//Moving the character
var update = function(modifier) {
    if(38 in keysDown) {
        hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if(40 in keysDown) {
        hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if(37 in keysDown) {
        hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if(39 in keysDown) {
        hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }
}

if (
    hero.x <= (monster.x + 32);
    && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32);
    && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32);
    && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32);
    ) {
        ++monsters.caught;
        reset();
    };

var render = function() {
    if(bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if(heroReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
    }

    if(monsterReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.font = "12pt Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseLine = "top";
    ctx.fillText = "Monsters Caught: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32)
};

var main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta/1000);
    render();

    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

P.S. I added an alert to the top of the js file but it only works when there is no code under it for some reason. If i delete all of my other code and just put alert("test"); it works but if I put all of my code back with the alert there is no code. I know this is a long post so if you have any questions please ask and i will clarify for you. Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: You should check your Javscript console to see what errors you are getting. You have several syntax errors. Open debugger is `ctrl + shift + i` in windows and `Cmd + Opt + i` in mac.

Comment: Oh geez that smells like a case of lack-of-debugging-tools. The best thing to do now is to start using something like firebug or chrome console to take a look at what's happening. Does it throw exceptions in the console? Something like bad syntax?

Comment: I am using a windows 8 code writer app from the App Store. I will check for a debugging tool when I get a chance. I'm just baffled because I have done everything the tutorial says (I have even  copy and pasted the code that the actual author used to make the game) and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok but first I'll harass Lost Decade Games on twitter why they have syntax errors in their tutorials :)

Comment: Haha. I just wanna figure this out soon.

Comment: @user3639468 (Bailey) they don't have these error in there tutorial provided, there are your typos, don't blame someone else on your own error

Comment: What are you talking about? I'm not blaming anyone but myself for my errors. Why else would I be here.

Comment: Ooh I just realized. How awkward^^

Answer (score 1):

there were some error in if condition (you pur semicolon there, line 90) and in filltext method (line 105)
updated script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="data" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        // Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/background.png";

// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/hero.png";

// Monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function () {
    monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "images/monster.png";

// Game objects
var hero = {
    speed: 256 // movement in pixels per second
};
var monster = {};
var monstersCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

//New game 
var reset = function() {
    hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
    hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

    monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
}

//Moving the character
var update = function(modifier) {
    if(38 in keysDown) {
        hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if(40 in keysDown) {
        hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if(37 in keysDown) {
        hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if(39 in keysDown) {
        hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }
}

if ( hero.x <= (monster.x + 32)
    && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32)
    && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32)
    && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)
    ) {
        ++monsters.caught;
        reset();
    };

var render = function() {
    if(bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if(heroReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
    }

    if(monsterReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.font = "12pt Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseLine = "top";
    //ctx.fillText = "Monsters Caught: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32)
    ctx.fillText("Monsters Caught:",32,32);
};

var main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta/1000);
    render();

    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

var then = Date.now();
reset();
main(); 
    }())


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 1

your file structurs should be like below

```
-index.html
-jquery
-images
--background.png
--monster.png
--hero.png
```

UPDATE 2
check [this](https://github.com/lostdecade/simple_canvas_game) for folder structure

Comment: I fixed those two errors. Could it possibly be a problem of not being able to locate the images? I have a large folder with a smaller folder containing the images in it. In that large folder I also have a is folder with the is file and the html document which is not in a separate folder.

Comment: @user3639468 see UPDATE 1 in my answer

Comment: @user3639468 see my answer's update 2 section there i provide a link for this game source files. hope this will help

Comment: Ah sorry yeah you did fix the dom ready problem, you placed the script at the end of body. I always forget that that's a thing now^^ But if he moves the script tags around the dom tree the code will break again. But nevermind. It's an irrelevant detail at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I haven't been replying. I appreciate all of your help. I finally got it to work. In case you were wondering, what I did was create the canvas in html rather than in javascript and it worked. I feel like I'm on cloud nine right now. Thanks for all your help I really do appreciate it.